# xelatex does not respect \ifpdf?

Tags: xetex

I have the following file, say `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\begin{document}
\ifpdf
bla
\else
blubb
\fi
\end{document}
```

The result is `bla` when I run with `pdflatex` or with `lualatex`
(which I would expect) but it is `blubb` if I run with `xelatex` (which I consider strange).

I know that `xelatex` creates PDF via intermediate XDV which is not PDF. ...
But still I would expect that `xelatex test` without options which creates PDF finally
would create a PDF containing `bla`.

Can anyone confirm the problem?
Do I do sth wrong???

Answer (score 7):

Using xetex is just like using (dvi) tex, with xdvipdfmx producing pdf from the generated dvi just as dvipdfm (or dvips+ps2pdf)  create pdf from the dvi generated by classic tex.  The fact that by default xdvipdfmx is run automatically does not change this basic workflow.

In particular any "back end" interaction for rotation, image inclusion etc has to work via `\special` inserted into a dvi file, picked up by `xdvipdfmx` you can not directly inject pdf literals, so `\ifpdf` needs to be false.

Comment: If I understand you right, for xetex and in particular xelatex \ifpdf is never satisfied, right?

Comment: @user2609605  yes, xelatex is always in dvi mode